# Javascript sorting array ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Hei guys.

I am trying to figure out why my code is not working and i simply can not find any reason for it. I am trying to sort my array by some property but i get this error : `ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.utils')`.
This is how I am using my sort method:

```
  this.myarray.sort(this.compareDates);
```

This is my sort method:

```
private compareDates(firstModel: myModel, secondModel: myModel): number{
    const firstDate = new Date(this.utils.stringFormatterForDate(firstModel.date));
    const secondDate = new Date(this.utils.stringFormatterForDate(secondModel.date));

    if(firstDate < secondDate){
      return -1;
    }
    if(firstDate > secondDate){
      return 1;
    }
  }
```

"utils" is a service which I am injecting through the constructor. If I use the service's method(stringFormatterForDate) anywhere else, it works without throwing any errors

Comment: did you initialize `utils`? it is likely to be undefined because it was never given a value

Comment: Is the method actually stored in `this`? And what is `this.myarray`?

Comment: The error means that `this.utils` is `undefined` (or possibly `this`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the sort method is being run in a different scope. Try this:

```
this.myarray.sort(this.compareDates.bind(this));
```

Comment: Got there first! Hahah

Comment: No, you didn't. This question was answered first in 2013 :)

Comment: Indeed. Touche.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `this.compareDates` to your object before passing it to `sort`. It doesn't pass the context when calling the comparison function.

```
this.myarray.sort(this.compareDates.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try binding to `this` (because of where `compareDates` is being called):

```
this.myarray.sort(this.compareDates.bind(this));
```